# Custom GET URL - str replace PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an issue on a recruitment website I'm working on. I am passing a get through URL to go to a specific position page on the website and I want to replace the current `quickapply.php` page holding after the position id by only the position title. My current solution is displaying something like that:

```
https://mywebsite.com/quickapply.php?id=93/Position-name-example
```

this is the code that I'm doing, but what I actually want is to display something like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/Position-name-example
```

or

```
https://mywebsite.com/quickapply.php/Position-name-example
```

But its been hard to make this change, despite it seems very simple

This is my code so far:

```
<a href="quickapply.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-',$row['title']); ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
```

Can someone help get that soution?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Get rid of `quickapply.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` in your `<a>` tag.

Comment: to go to a specific position on a page (dom-element with a specific id) you can just add location hash like `mywebsite.com#position`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:
`<a href="/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-',$row['title']); ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>`

or 
`<a href="quickapply.php/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-',$row['title']); ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>`